# Processing Large Amount of Data in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

What should I do if I am processing large amount of data and the form will become white when I minimized it but it will back to it's original form when the processing of file is complete.

ex:

this is what happened when I minimized the form.

[image]

and this is what happened after the processing of large amount of data.. It will back to it's original form.

[image]

all I want to do is that, even though I am minimizing the form, the form will not turn into white and  to show what is happening to the progress of processing of file..

I am using visual studio 2008, and C# language.

Comment: Use another thread to perform the processing of the large amount of data in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Massimiliano's answer implies, the reason for the white window is that you are performing processing on the UI thread.  Since it is busy doing whatever (encrypting a file, by the looks of it), the thread isn't free to draw the window.

Look into the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class for good examples of how to do the processing on a background thread.  There is an example about halfway down the page in the link above.

Comment: Backgroundworkers are good but are Tasks not a lot easier to use?

Comment: Tasks are available for DN 4 and greater. BackgroundWorker is compatible with DN 1.0

Comment: Tasks are fine, but in this case I am guessing that the OP wants to report status back to the UI, and the BackgroundWorker is readily set up to do that (including marshalling events to the UI for you).  Using Tasks, you need to do that manually using Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example where you should use MultiThread

have a look at the below:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't told us what you are processing here is a sample

```
//this starts the new thread
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{

   //do you stuff here, I added a windows directory file search
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");

   //searches for all files on your computer, it will run for a while, stops after it finds 200
   foreach(var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*" + textBox1.Text + "*.doc?", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Take(200))
   {
      this.BeginInvoke( new Action(() =>
         {
            //this sends information back to the main ui thread it can be any method at all
            Files.Add(file);
         }));
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your long running work execute on a back ground thread (or worker thread), so that will leave your UI thread to be responsive to the user. You see the "white" because your UI thread is blocked while the long running work is executed.

There are plenty of examples if you Google around, [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

The **most elegant** solution would probably be to make do your lengthy process in a different thread.  Make sure if you do this that you temporarily disable the user interface (perhaps by showing a small progress screen modally).  As Chris Shain suggested, the [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is probably the way to go.

If you are looking for the **shortest possible** answer and you have access to some progress event in your [en|de]cryption algorithm, you can call [form.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) periodically to repaint the screen.

Comment: form.Refresh() will not redraw from because message loop is not processing while UI thread is busy. Application.DoEvents should be used to process application message queue.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh, thanks for clarifying that.  You are right, the form.Refresh would only work if there was an event or callback raised by the long-running algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWworker is a type of multithreading.   I think it is a little easier than using threading directly.

[backgroudworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

On the dowork is when you would encrypt or decrypt.  And pass the arguements (file and encryption mode) in DoWorkEventArgs e.  In RunWorkerCompleted is when you could display a message it is complete.   Or have a ListView of completed files.  You could even leave the Encryptoin Mode and Open File Hot while the Encrypt / Decrypt is working.  Then on the RunWorkerCompleted is when you would enable the Encypt and Decrypt button.

Answer (score 0):

Until your application is calculating the UI thread isn't processing messagegs, so you have a white from.

You have two ways to solve it:

1. Move all of your calculations into separated thread.
2. Call the Application.DoEvents() from your calculation code, this is bad parctice but it works

Multithreading example:

```
private void ButtonClick(...)
{
  ((Action)Calculation).BeginInvoke(null, null);
}

private void Calculation()
{
  your calculations here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows form you should use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to work in the background and do not stop de UI Thread